# Pandas transforming chronological rows to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table of work experiences where each row represents a job in chronological order from the first job to the most recent job. For data science purposes I'm trying to create a new table based on this table that displays new job attributes and old job attributes on the same row. For example, the original table would be like:

| uniqueID | personID | startdate | enddate | title | functions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | 1/1/21 | 12/1/21 | Analyst | data science |
| 2 | A1 | 1/1/22 | 12/1/22 | Manager | admin |

The new table would be something like this:

| uniqueID | personID | new_title | new_function | old_title | old_function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | Analyst | data science | nan | nan |
| 2 | A1 | Manager | admin | Analyst | data science |

I tried to use some groupby variations but haven't been able to get this result.

Comment: So are you basically just copying and then shifting the `title` and `functions` columns down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for a shift:

```
cols = ['title', 'functions']
df[['old_' + c for c in cols]] = df.groupby('personID')[cols].shift(1)
df = df.drop(['startdate', 'enddate'], axis=1).rename({c: 'new_' + c for c in cols}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   uniqueID personID new_title new_functions old_title old_functions
0         1       A1   Analyst  data science       NaN           NaN
1         2       A1   Manager         admin   Analyst  data science
```